# Automatically inferring types from overridden interfaces in TypeScript

Tags: javascript, typescript, types

I'm trying to create some TypeScript definitions for modules that already exist.  In a particular interface to be implemented, the signature looks like this:

```
type NextFunction<T> = () => T;
type Response = string[] | Promise<string[]>;

interface IPage {
  getBodyClasses(next: NextFunction<Response>): Response;
}
```

The parameter and return structures are fixed, and I'd really like to be able to have TypeScript infer what the parameter types are of my overridden methods.  However, when I create my override, I see that the parameter implicitly has an `any` type.

```
class Page implements IPage {
  getBodyClasses(next) {
    return next();
  }
}
```

Is there any way to mark `getBodyClasses` as a dedicated override so that the types for parameters are automatically inferred?  It would already say that `Page` was improperly implementing the interface if I typed `next` as `number`, so I don't quite understand why it can't also then infer the type of `next` is the same as the interface's.

Comment: Here's a link for the issue you opened for future readers: [Type inference for method overrides in derived classes](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/issues/16590)

Answer (score 1):

Contextual typing of implemented properties is not supported.

## More

The main issue that tracked this is https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/issues/1373