# Use the parent class's method types in Typescript

Tags: class, typescript, inheritance

I'm noticing that the types don't flow through when you extend a class and I'm wondering if there's a way to enforce that in the type definition? Here's some psuedo code:

```
class A {
  render(props: Object) {

  }
}

class B extends A {
  render(props) { <- right now its an any type, I'd like it to inherit from A

  } 
}
```

I am hoping for something like this:

```
class A {
  render(props: Object) {

  }
}

class B extends A {
  render(props: this.props) {

  } 
}
```

Cheers!

Comment: see also https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44596117/automatically-inferring-types-from-overridden-interfaces-in-typescript

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to redefine the type for that method again. However if you define one that's looser than the base class you'll get an error.

This works:

```js
class A {
  render(props: string) {

  }
}

class B extends A {
    render(props: string) {

  } 
}
```

This doesn't:

```js
class A {
  render(props: string) {

  }
}

class B extends A {
    render(props: number) {

  } 
}
```

Comment: if this answer is what you have been looking for please mark it as the correct one as well, so other people will know too. :)